# Does Trimec kill grasses (fescue)

Tags: lawn, weed-control, grass, weeds

Located in North Carolina. Mostly a fescue lawn. well established, some new sod from last fall, some new grass seed from this spring. Let, I have weeds. Some areas of my lawn are fighting a good blanket of what looks a variant of spurweed.

I hear Trimec works well. will Trimec affect/kill/damage my existing grass, new grass, or germinating grass? (fescue)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I used Trimec at a concentration above the recommended last summer in 90 degree heat on fescue. There was minimal damage to the grass, but it worked very well on the weeds. This was on a rental where the yard was overgrown with creeping charlie, wild strawberries, etc. I killed all the weeds off in July, aerated, seeded and fertilized in the fall. It looks like a golf course now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Trimec on Fescue. It will harm the turf grass.

Try Scott's products, Step 1, 2, 3, and 4 for weed control.

Cut your lawn at about 3 1/4 - 3 1/2 inches in height.
Aerate your soil & Dethatch it.
Water your grass once every 4-5 days for a good 20 minutes or so to establish strong root systems.

Cutting the grass higher is similar to giving the grass a hair cut but cutting the head off weeds - the grass will receive sunlight instead of the weeds.

Aerating and Dethatching your soil helps grow strong root systems for your lawn, making the grass thicker - reducing weeds.

Watering does the same, stronger grass less weeds.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for this. Just to confirm, in researching more after your answer, I found directions for trimec, snippet follows below. the trimec directions state I can use trimec on fescuve just as long as ambient temps is less than 80. what's your experience on this?

Comment: http://www.pbigordon.com/pdfs/TrimecPlus-SL.pdf

Comment: http://www.lawnsite.com/archive/index.php/t-232387.html

Comment: It's a risk - it may work out for you it may not. I have read the best way to remove Spurweeds is to pull them (with roots) - trying the Trimec is completely up to you, I have damaged a Fescue lawn trying to kill Creeping Charlie with Trimec however.